# php drops file type error for file size

Tags: php, forms, validation

Fellas,
I've run in an interesting bug in my code and I can't figure out the reason.

I have a form with 3 fields. Name, email, file upload fields. After the fields are filled it sends the stuff back to the same file.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])&&!empty($_POST['name'])){ echo $_POST['name'];}?>" maxlength="100" />
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])&&!empty($_POST['email'])){ echo $_POST['email'];}?>" maxlength="50" />
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2097152" /> <input type="file" name="file_upload" size="15" value="<?php if(isset($_FILES["file_upload"]["name"])&&!empty($_FILES["file_upload"]["name"])){ echo $_FILES["file_upload"]["name"];}?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" id="image-button" />
</form>
```

So the form sent back to the index.php. Now the error handling: (the values of the error fields are in Hungarian, but I translate the necessary fields)

```
$upload_errors = array(
// http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
  UPLOAD_ERR_OK         => "Nincsenek hibák.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE   => "Nagyobb a megengedett fileméretnél.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE  => "Nagyobb a form megengedett fileméreténél.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL    => "Részleges feltöltés.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE    => "File nem található.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => "Átmeneti könyvtár nem található.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => "Nem írható cél mappa.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION  => "Hibás kiterjesztés."
);



if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $errors = array();

  $required_fields = array('name' => 'A név megadása kötelező.', 'email' => 'E-mail cím megadása kötelező.' );
  foreach($required_fields as $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$key]) || empty($_POST[$key])) { 
        $errors[] = $value; 
    }
  }

if(!is_valid_email($_POST['email'])){
    $errors[] = 'Set a correct mail address.';
    }

if($_FILES["file_upload"]["size"]>2097152){
    $errors[] = 'Maximum 2MB file size.';
    }   

if(!isset($_FILES["file_upload"]["name"])||empty($_FILES["file_upload"]["name"])){
    $errors[] = 'You must upload a picture!';
    }   

if (($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] !== "image/png")&& ($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] !== "image/jpg") && ($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] !== "image/jpeg") && ($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] !== "image/pjpeg")){
    $errors[] = 'Only PNG or JPG/JPEG files allowed.';
    }
```

When I try to upload a file with a file size 2MB+ the error returns:

- Only PNG or JPG/JPEG files allowed. -

This error belongs to the file type! The form validation returns a different error!

***Question:***

Why is this happen? Why don't triggers the Maximum 2MB file size. error???

Comment: Try debugging your script: `$errors[] = 'Only PNG or JPG/JPEG files allowed. File size: '.$_FILES["file_upload"]["size"];`

Comment: I believe it should be OR and not AND. So if it's one of those file types then accept it.

Comment: This probably won't help with your specific problem, but... 1) you can't rely on the MIME type for validating the format of the file, browsers may not send it at all and you can easily spoof it. But if you are going to rely on this, you can make your code easier to read, and easier to add new types, by creating an array of your allowed mime types (let's call it `$allowedTypes`), and then checking it by calling `in_array($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"],$allowedTypes)`

Comment: @Matt not true, because he is checking if it is NOT equal to AND NOT equal to... So when it is equal to one of them the expression evaluates to TRUE

Comment: What's the upload limit in php.ini?

Comment: @DaveRandom yea your right, too tired, everything is jumbled together, but i was going to suggest what you suggested as well.

Comment: @Matt well you know what they say about great minds...

Comment: Try a var_dump($_FILES) if you can and see what values you get for files above 2MB.

Answer (score 1):

If a file is bigger than [`upload_max_filesize`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) (which is usually 2MB), PHP will ignore the file, set `['size']` to `0` and `['error']` to [`UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Check `['error']` instead of `['size']`.

See http://docs.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

BTW you should not rely on `["type"]`, it's set by the client, and the client can set it to anything he wants.